# Kinect stops when moving motor

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo.

Also, I'm using pointcloud_to_laserscan package for the kinect and it's working fine.

The problem is whenever I send a command to run the motors, the kinect stops and the laptop cannot detect that the kinect is connected.

NOTE: The kinect and the motor controller are connected through 2 USB ports.

I think the problem is in the laptop, because I tried another laptop and they work fine.

Unfortunately, I can't use the good laptop due to RAM problem.

Any idea??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207710/kinect-stops-when-moving-motor/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-04-24**:
Sounds like an EMI problem. Where does the motor and where does Kinect get the power from? Is the Laptop connected to the same power source (battery). Whats the whole setup?

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-04-24**:
@cyborg-x1 The motors get the power from 24 volt battery, where the kinect is connected to AC. The laptop uses its own battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I think it could really be some EMI thing.
That the motor interferes with the Kinect or the USB communication.
I once did a very simple microcontroller board for a fellow student,
it should just turn on the motor depending on input states, but the motor created
huge emissions so that when you put on an oscilloscope it showed a huge spike without
connection to the motor when the motor was running. Also when it was running, it never stopped,
except someone touched the microcontroller package with his finger.

To get rid of that, an laboratory assistant told us to solder capacitors (100nF) to the motor pins and connect them with the case. After that it was gone. The motor was a simple brushed DC motor. Maybe you could try something similar, if it is a DC motor.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0